# How do I label two vectors in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, vector

I have a 2 column matrix(called `M`, which I visualize as two vectors using Matlab's `plot` command(`plot(M)`). I have two issues:

1. I want to label the vectors themselves on the plot.
2. I want to label each row of the matrix(i.e. each vector component) on the plot.

How would I go about doing those things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example:

```
M = cumsum(rand(10,2) - 0.5);
x = 1:size(M,1);
plot(x, M(:,1), 'b.-', x, M(:,2), 'g.-')
legend('M1', 'M2')
for i=x
    text(i+0.1, M(i,1), sprintf('%.2f', M(i,1)), 'FontSize',7, 'Color','b');
    text(i+0.1, M(i,2), sprintf('%.2f', M(i,2)), 'FontSize',7, 'Color','g');
end
```

[image: plot]

Alternatively, you can use:

```
datacursormode()
```

which will enable the user to just [point and click on points](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/data-cursor-displaying-data-values-interactively.html) to see the data labels.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to tweak this to get the positions of the labels exactly how you want them, but something like this will do the trick.

```
M = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
plot(M)
nrows = size(M, 1);
ncols = size(M, 2);
x = repmat(nrows - .3, 1, ncols);
y = M(end, :) - .3;
labels = cellstr([repmat('Col', ncols, 1), num2str((1:ncols)')]);
text(x, y, labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can label each axis with the function:

```
xlabel('label')
ylabel('label')
```

These can also take cell arguments, where each row is a new line.  That's handy for showing units.  Labeling each point on the figure can be done as so:

```
for i=1:length(M)
    text(M(i,1),M(i,2),'Label Text')
end
```

The label text can also be a string variable that you can edit with sprintf and make special strings for each point.

Comment: It's not the axes I want to label; it's the vectors themselves.

Comment: So you're not plotting M(:,1) vs M(:,2), but rather each column against length(M(:,1)) ?  If that's the case, then you can use either the commands:

    text(M(1,1),M(1,1),'Label 1'),text(M(1,2),M(1,2),'Label 2')

or

    annotation()
  
or

    legend('Label 1','Label 2')

The manual pages have a few examples for this.  Text is used the same as before, but for only one point on each line.  The annotation function is a lot more useful, but it has lots of options and style capabilities.  I threw legend in there as well if you don't want to clutter the plot window.