# Data label on each entry in xy scatter

Tags: matlab

I have an x-y scatter plot in MATLAB and want to put a data label on each point.  I can't seem to find this in the documentation.  Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Labeling points in order in a plot in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140312/labeling-points-in-order-in-a-plot-in-matlab), [How do I label two vectors in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243069/how-do-i-label-two-vectors-in-matlab)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Example:

```
p = rand(10,2);
scatter(p(:,1), p(:,2), 'filled')
axis([0 1 0 1])

labels = num2str((1:size(p,1))','%d');    %'
text(p(:,1), p(:,2), labels, 'horizontal','left', 'vertical','bottom')
```

[image]